# Is load balancing a built-in feature of SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Is load balancing a built-in feature of SharePoint 2010, in case you want to use multiple web servers in a three tier topology (web servers, app servers and then database servers). If not, what do you suggest? Hardware NLB, Software (OS or some other service/app), what's the best option in case of SharePoint 2010 installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The various levels will each take the load their supposed to process, but if you have multiple (eg, multiple web servers) you will need to use a hardware load balancer, or MS's built-in NLB feature (or possibly a 3rd party software).

**Edit:**
To install MS NLB, follow [MS's instructions here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731695.aspx). Then configure SharePoint for it. [Instructions for WFE servers here](http://fabiangwilliams.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/setting-up-nlb-for-your-wfes-in-sharepoint/). Depending on the versions your using, the process might be slightly different. Those should get you pointed in the right direction at least. There's also quite a bit available by Googling "SharePoint NLB [service]" where [service] is the part of SharePoint that you're trying to load balance.

Comment: Can you tell me more about MS's built-in NLB feature? Is there a command to start it?

Comment: Thx Chris. This helps a lot.